# How to access a specific child in css?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, angular7

I have the following html

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor='let item of this.shop[selectedShop].items>
            <td>
              <div class="fade-in">
                <div style="flex: 5" class="p-2">
                  <h2 class="p-1">{{item.name}}</h2>
                  <ul class="subtitle">
                    <li *ngFor='let article of product.articles'>
                      <div style="line-height: 24px" class="">
                        <p>{{article.name}}</p>
                        <p class="text-muted">{{article.description}}</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>    
                  <p [innerHTML]="item.description" *ngIf=" item && item.description"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
</tbody>
```

in this case I get 5 "td" with their respective elements.
But in the case of the ul with class "subtitle" I wish that it appears in all but the third of the "td".
For this I have applied the following css

```
  tbody tr td .subtitle:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
```

In this case it doesn't work, but if I remove the reference to the :nth it works for all with subtitle class.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `tbody tr:nth-child(3) td .subtitle` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you!! I was blocked and couldn't see the solution.